# Example of Non-Conformally Flat Einstein Manifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Does there exist an [Einstein manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_manifold) which is not conformally flat, which is to say one which has non-vanishing [Weyl tensor.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_tensor) If so, what is a good example.

Comment: Since I don't do Riemannian geometry anymore, I might have this wrong. It seems to me that if the traceless Ricci and Weyl tensors vanish, then the Riemann curvature has to be of the form $R_{ijkl} = k(g_{ik}g_{jl}-g_{il}g_{jk})$, where, by the Bianchi identities, $k$ is constant. So conformally flat Einstein metrics have constant sectional curvature. If this is correct, then the simplest non-conformally-flat Einstein metric that comes to mind is complex projective space with complex dimension greater than $1$.

Comment: @DeaneYang:  Indeed, you are correct; conformally flat and Einstein implies constant sectional curvature in dimensions greater than $2$.  The Fubini-Study metric on $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is Einstein but not conformally flat.

Comment: Another example is $S^2\times S^2$ with the standard product metric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All conformally flat homogeneous riemannian manifolds are symmetric spaces, by a result of Takagi.  All homogeneous riemannian manifolds of dimension $\leq 11$ admit Einstein metrics, by results of Wang and Ziller.  Most homogensous riemannian manifolds are not symmetric spaces.

### References:

Takagi, H.: Conformally flat Riemannian manifolds admitting a transitive group of isometries
I, II. Tohoku Math. J. 27, 103–110(I), 445–451(II) (1975)

McKenzie Y. Wang, Wolfgang Ziller: Existence and non-existence of homogeneous Einstein metrics, Inventiones mathematicae, 1986, Volume 84, Issue 1, pp 177-194

Answer (score 4):

K3 surface is Einstein, by Calabi-Yau theorem, but it is not conformally flat; this can be seen e.g. from topology, or from the reference that José Figueroa-O'Farrill has given above.

Answer (score 3):

Does your question refer to both Riemannian and semi-Riemannian spaces? If so, then the [Schwarzschild metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric) is an example. It's a vacuum solution to the Einstein field equations (with zero cosmological constant), so it's an Einstein manifold. It has a nonvanishing Weyl tensor.

Answer (score 3):

By the [standard curvature decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_decomposition), for an Einstein metric, if the Weyl curvature vanishes, then the sectional curvature is constant, so other than space forms, all Einstein manifolds are not conformally flat.

Sorry I didn't see Deane Yang's answer, he already got this answer.

Comment: Oops. I forgot that Einstein already implies constant scalar curvature.